# Cannot login to Drupal Site deployed on Ubuntu VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, drupal-7

I deployed Drupal site on Virtual Box Ubuntu. I am not able to login to the /user page. It does not give error message or login successfully. Can you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect us to answer to this? You did not specify _any_ details about your situation! But maybe a general hint: you have to start reading your http servers error log file. That should _always_ be the first thing you do when developing php stuff based on an http server and you run into problems. Why _guess_ what the issue might be, if you can simply look into that file and _read_ what the issue _is_?

Comment: Apologies for inadequate question.  I am new to Drupal. I will put in the error log file details.

Comment: Don't get clear words wrong :-) We are all here to help and learn. A question is _never_ inadequate. Unless it is intended to be, of course.

Comment: There is no error. It just doesnt give any information. Not in error.log or access.log. Am I looking in wrong place. (/var/log/apache2)

Comment: Next place is your browsers developer console (typically F12 or, on exotic systems, right click and something like "inspect element"). Both, the javascript console and the network tab.

Comment: Checked fiddler.. it gives 404 - Not found. Any idea?

Comment: Well, http status 404 means you try to "load" something that does not exist, so the URL you use is wrong. But as said above: we cannot help you, if you do not tell us your code and the details of the request. So what URL is it trying to load?

Answer (score 0):

Enabled module rewrite. `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Then restart apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

This resolved the issue.